# Import KMZ with raster to GeoServer

Tags: raster, geoserver, import, kmz

I have a KMZ file which contains shapefiles as well as their corresponding satellite images. I want to upload it to GeoServer as a layer. I tried uploading the KMZ file using Data Importer tool from GeoServer, but it gives an error of wrong file format. I followed several answers and one of the suggested method was to upload the KMZ to postgres and then call it inside GeoServer. However, the examples shown are all related to shapefiles in KMZ, and not raster.

I don't understand the solution to it.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Are yo sure you have shapefiles inside the KMZ, and not vector data created from shapefiles.

Answer (score 2):

**KMZ** files typically contain KML (Keyhole Markup Language) files, which are a type of XML that describes geographic features and placemarks. GeoServer, as a server for serving geographic data, primarily supports vector data (points, lines, and polygon) stored in formats such as Shapefiles and GeoJSON. **If your KMZ file contains satellite images, it's likely that they are in a raster format, such as JPEG or PNG, which is not directly supported by GeoServer.**

To upload the KMZ file containing satellite images to GeoServer, you will need to convert the raster images into a format that GeoServer can understand, such as GeoTIFF or other supported formats listed in the following link: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/index.html

Once you have converted the satellite images into a supported format, you can either:

- Publish the raster data directly from GeoServer by adding a new layer
  and selecting the raster format file.
- Import the raster data into a spatial database such as PostgreSQL with PostGIS extension, and then serve it through GeoServer as a WMS or WCS layer.

In the case of the second option, you will need to use a tool like **ogr2ogr** to import the raster data into the spatial database. Once the data is in the database, you can configure GeoServer to use the PostGIS layer as a data source and serve it as a **WMS** or WCS layer.

The exact steps to achieve this will depend on the tools and software that you are using, as well as the specifics of your data and requirements. However, the above steps should give you a general idea of what needs to be done to serve your KMZ file containing satellite images in GeoServer.